# How to change pycharm 5.0.1 cursor

Tags: pycharm

I would like to change the mouse cursor type in pycharm 5.0.1 . I would like the normal line cursor like for word editors and not this kind of selection cursor. Kindly assist am new to python and using pycharm.

[image: cursor]

Comment: I think you pressed `insert` key on keyboard !!

Comment: Yo are right Arman. I must have done that unknowingly. Thanks really appreciate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you have gone into *overwrite* mode.

1. Check what keyboard shortcut may be assigned to that in *Preferences → Keymap → Editor Actions → Toggle Insert/Overwrite.*

   [image: preferences]
2. If it has no keyboard shortcut, or you can't be bothered to remember it, you can toggle it by [pressing <kbd>Command/Ctrl + Shift + A</kbd>](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-to-action.html), type "overwrite" in the popup, which should bring up the *"Toggle Insert/Overwrite"* option, and hit enter.

   [image: toggle]

Comment: It reads insert as the keyboard short cut for Toggle Insert/Overwrite.

Comment: Then you should be able to toggle it on/off with the *Insert* key on your keyboard; or option 2 I mention.

Comment: Did that. Works fine now. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 17):

By default in Mac any editor comes with insert mode like In PyCharm :

So we need to uninstall the VIM from Pycharm in this case

Preferences ---> Plugins ----> VIM (uninstall) and restart the py charm

Comment: Exact answer. Please follow this for the resolution.

Answer (score 13):

Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> **Use Block Caret**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

For saving the trouble to keep toggling between the line cursor and selection cursor, here is a setting you need to change:

In you Pycharm editor,Tools->Vim Emulator(you need to uncheck this)

Answer (score 4):

At the bottom part of PyCharm IDE, there's a `V button`. Click on that `V` button then `untick` the `enable` option.

If the `V button` is colorful, it means that you're in `Vim mode`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Please click on the "insert" key in the keyboard. It worked for me.

### [image: Insert key]

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and disable the Vim editor from plug-ins

Answer (score 0):

For saving the trouble to keep toggling between the line cursor and selection cursor, which is caused due to VIM in PyCharm.

Setting/Plugin/Installed/VIM (you can either disable or uninstall).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows OS. You can use the key at the same time shift+ins

Answer (score -3):

1. Step: `ctrl` + `shift` + `A`
2. Step: Search `Block Caret`
3. Step: enable it.

Comment: This will keep the Block caret and the OP wants to remove it.